# Правильно составить SQL запрос для MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблицы:

`books
-id
-title
-pubDate`

`authors
-id
-name`

`publish
-id
-name`

`book_author
-book_id
-author_id`

`book_publish
-book_id
-publish_id`

Необходимо выбрать список самых продуктивных (кол-во книг в год),
авторов для каждого издательства.
Помогите пожалуйста! 3й день не могу придумать.

UPD1:

Вот что я смог родить:

```
SELECT a.firstName, a.middleName,a.lastName, b.title, p.name, COUNT(b.id) as cnt
FROM authors as a, books as b, author_book as ab, publishing as p
WHERE p.id = 3 AND ab.book_id = b.id AND b.pubDate > '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY b.id
HAVING cnt > 5
```

UPD2:

Рабочий запрос:

```
SELECT
  a.firstName, p.name,
  COUNT(ab.author_id) AS total
FROM 
  books AS b
JOIN 
  publish_book AS pb 
ON 
  pb.book = b.uid
JOIN 
  author_book AS ab 
ON 
  b.uid = ab.book_id
JOIN 
  authors AS a 
ON 
  ab.author_id = a.uid
JOIN 
  publishing as p 
ON 
  p.uid = pb.publish
WHERE
  p.id = 4 AND
  YEAR(b.pubDate) = 2016
GROUP BY
  ab.author_id 
ORDER BY
  total DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Что вы пытались сделать? Что у вас не получилось? Предоставьте запрос, который вы написали

Comment: @tCode, наверно мне стоило написать - "Напишите за меня". Т.к. у меня совсем нет хотя бы как-то более-менее работающих вариантов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно начать отталкиваться от следующего запроса, который выводит список авторов, работавших на издательство (с идентификатором 3) в 2016 году, в порядке убывания количества изданных книг.

```
SELECT
  a.name,
  COUNT(ba.author_id) AS total
FROM
  books AS b
JOIN
  book_publish AS bp
ON
  b.id = bp.book_id
JOIN
  book_author AS ba
ON
  b.id = ba.book_id
JOIN
  authors AS a
ON
  ba.author_id = a.id
WHERE
  bp.publish_id = 3 AND
  YEAR(b.pubDate) = 2016
GROUP BY
  ba.author_id
ORDER BY
  total DESC
```

Результат выглядит примерно так

```
+--------------+-------+
| name         | total |
+--------------+-------+
| Автор 2      |     3 |
| Автор 3      |     3 |
| Автор 4      |     2 |
| Автор 5      |     2 |
| Автор 1      |     1 |
+--------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT TOP 1
      p.name AS publish
    , a.name AS autor
    , COUNT(a.name) AS cnt
FROM 
    book_publish AS bp
    INNER JOIN publish AS p ON bp.publish_id = p.id
    INNER JOIN books AS b ON bp.book_id = b.id
    INNER JOIN book_autors AS ba ON b.id = ba.book_id
    INNER JOIN autors AS a ON ba.author_id = a.id
WHERE YEAR(b.pubDate) = 2016
GROUP BY 
      p.name
    , a.name
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Правда тут будет одна проблема, если имеется несколько авторов, имеющих максимальное количество книг, для данного издательства, выведен будет только один из них (и нет гарантии что каждый раз это будет один и тот же автор).
Либо:

```
SELECT
      publish
    , autor 
   FROM
   (
   SELECT
          p.name AS publish
        , a.name AS autor
        , COUNT(a.name) AS cnt
    FROM 
        book_publish AS bp
        INNER JOIN publish AS p ON bp.publish_id = p.id
        INNER JOIN books AS b ON bp.book_id = b.id
        INNER JOIN book_autors AS ba ON b.id = ba.book_id
        INNER JOIN autors AS a ON ba.author_id = a.id
    WHERE YEAR(b.pubDate) = 2016
    GROUP BY 
          p.name
        , a.name
    ) as tmp
HAVING tmp.cnt = MAX(tmp.cnt)
```

**ССЫЛКИ:**

1. [SELECT id HAVING maximum count of id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249689/select-id-having-maximum-count-of-id)
2. [Агрегатная функция от агрегатной функци](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_aggregate_function_to_aggregate_function/page1.html)